# Ionic Simple Map, No google

Tags: ionic-framework, geolocation, ionic4

i'm looking to implement a simple map localization, but i don't want to use Google map because my purpose don't need further options : Just a simple localization in an abstract map.

Where can i find a good documentation for that ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found that we can integrate leaflet which is an open source interactive map :

[Leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/)

[Tutorial to integrate it](https://medium.com/@bviveksingh96/using-leaflet-with-ionic-4-f7acbd1c2464)